# How to check for dates entered mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access

## Goal

I am working in a MS Access database. I need to identify cases where DateCollected is input wrong by the user. Specifically, when the user entered mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy. These have to be found after-the-fact because there is no data validation at point of entry.

I have a reference date, DateEntry, that I know is correct because it is time-stamped by the database. I have identified these ways to validate collection date:

1. The user can't accidentally enter dd/mm/yyyy as mm/dd/yyyy if the day is >12.
2. DateCollected can't be after DateEntry. Collection always happens first.
3. Looking at the spread between DateCollected and DateEntry. If it's larger than 60 days I suspect a bad input. To confirm, I reverse the month and day to create a NewDate, and if the recalculated spread is fewer than 60 days, I can classify the error.

## Query

```
SELECT [T].[DateCollected], 
[T].[DateEntry], 
[T].[DateEntry]-[T].[DateCollected] AS Spread,
DateSerial(Year([T].[DateCollected]),Day([T].[DateCollected]),Month([T].[DateCollected])) AS NewDate, 
[T].[DateEntry]-[NewDate] AS NewSpread
FROM T
WHERE ((Day([T].[DateCollected])<=12))
ORDER BY [T].[DateEntry]-[T].[DateCollected] DESC
```

## Output

```
| DateCollected |  DateEntry   | Spread |   NewDate   | NewSpread |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  12/02/2004   |  17/12/2004  |   309  |  02/12/2004 |    15     |
|  11/02/2009   |  03/12/2009  |   295  |  02/11/2009 |    31     |
|  12/05/2008   |  19/02/2009  |   283  |  05/12/2008 |    76     |
|  10/01/2010   |  14/10/2010  |   277  |  01/10/2010 |    13     |
|  11/12/2007   |  26/06/2008  |   198  |  12/11/2007 |    227    |
|  03/07/2007   |  20/11/2007  |   140  |  07/03/2007 |    258    |
|  12/04/2008   |  28/08/2008  |   137  |  04/12/2008 |    -98    |
|  05/06/2013   |  15/05/2013  |   -21  |  15/05/2013 |     9     |
|  01/10/2005   |  18/01/2005  |  -256  |  18/01/2005 |     8     |
```

## Problem

I am having troubles writing the query this way because for some reason I cannot apply a filter to the NewSpread column. For example, I would want to filter out any cases where the NewSpread is negative (violation of rule #2 above) or when NewSpread>Spread (not caused by mixing up mm and dd). When I try to include a filter e.g.

```
WHERE ((Day([T].[DateCollected])<=12)) AND (([T].[DateEntry]-[NewDate])>0)
```

I get an error where it asks for a parameter value for NewDate.

[image]

## Questions

How can I fix my query so it allows filters on the NewSpread column?

Is there a better way to look for dates entered as mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: Could you edit your post and type in the exact error message?

Comment: you cannot use name `NewSpread` as it does not exists at the filtering time, you have to use full expression instead like `([T].[DateEntry]-[NewDate]) > 10`

Comment: Does that mean NewDate does not exist either?

Comment: yes, NewDate does not exist during `where` evaluation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that these expressions have to be repeated, even the expression for [NewDate], because you cannot use the given aliases in the `WHERE` clause.

However, it becomes easier, if you wrap the query in another one, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT   [DateCollected], 
             [DateEntry], 
             DateDiff("d", [DateCollected], [DateEntry]) AS Spread,
             Iif(DateCollected IS NULL, 0, DateSerial(Year([DateCollected]),Day([DateCollected]),Month([DateCollected]))) AS NewDate, 
             DateDiff("d", [NewDate], [DateEntry]) AS NewSpread
    FROM     T
    WHERE    Day([DateCollected]) <= 12
) AS Main
WHERE    [Main].[NewSpread] > 0 
ORDER BY [Main].[Spread] DESC
```

So now you can do a `WHERE` condition on [NewSpread].

NB: I am surprised to see that `[DateEntry]-[NewDate] AS NewSpread` works in the inner `SELECT`, since already there [NewDate] is an alias. If this turns out to be a problem, then do this calculation in the outer `SELECT`.

For more complex queries you might even want to wrap the outer query itself again in another wrapping `SELECT`.

The data type mismatch you experienced can be circumvented by using the [DateDiff function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php) and counting the number of days between two dates.

If you want that number to include decimals, the use minutes and divide, for example:

```
DateDiff("n", [DateCollected], [DateEntry])/60/24 AS Spread
```

Comment: I made a sub-query as you have. Without the external `WHERE [NewSpread] >0` condition the query works fine. If I include the condition, I get an error message: _Data type mismatch in criteria expression_.

Comment: See update. I suggest using the DateDiff function to calculate date differences. That should work with comparisons.

Comment: In DateDiff is "n" used for minute? It should be days for my purposes.

Comment: Yes, I took minutes to be sure that you would detect smaller differences as well. But yes, with "d", it would be days. Answer updated.

Comment: Hmm. Even using DateDiff to calculate the spreads in the inner query, I still get the _Data type mismatch in criteria expression_ error when I include the where condition in the outer query.

Comment: Still gives the same error with all of those changes. Since I'm in MS Access, in Datasheet view I can click on the NewSpread column drop down and it shows sort options and number filters. Everything I'm seeing suggests Access recognizes this as a number. However, when I make a custom filter like _NewSpread is great than or equal to..._ and put in 0, it asks me to enter a valid value.

Comment: Could the NewSpread column be formatted as a date since it's derived from the DateDiff function?

Comment: I think I need to break this out into a new question.. I added the following column to the inside query `IIf(NewSpread<0,"<0",">0") AS Classify` and it evaluates correctly in the query results. How can that be?

Comment: Nope that's it. I even tried putting another query outside of your solution, and using the WHERE condition on that query. But it didn't work either.

Comment: In the meantime I create the database myself in MS Access 2007, and although I could reproduce the original problem (asking for a parameter), I don't have a problem with the query I suggested. Can you confirm that the data type of `DateEntry` and `DateCompleted` is `Date/Time` (check in table design)?

Comment: Can confirm. I also tried to reproduce the problem in a second database with example data. Your query worked in that test. However, with my actual database (75000+ rows) the same query doesn't work. Haven't narrowed down the problem yet.

Comment: I found the problem happening if a *DateCollected* value is NULL. I think I have a solution for that. See my updated answer, which now includes an `Iif(DateCollected IS NULL, 0, ...)` wrapper around the `DateSerial` code. Could you try with that query?

Comment: Having a Null DateCollected caused the issue. Your solution is very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should define you `parameter` as a `date`. To do this, go to design view, open the Query Parameters dialog, paste the name of [your parameter] and set its data type to `Date`.  This way, Access will make sure it's a valid date. The user will be able to use any valid date format.
As an added bonus, if you query SQL server or Oracle linked tables, you might see a much improved performance, since your parameter is now properly *typed*.
This won't help you for dates like 7/5/2015, but you can ask your users to enter 7-May-2015.

Comment: Yes, in the future it will be necessary to have such a system. My problem though is dates that have already been entered, and looking for ones that could have been entered backwards.